# Update the values which is in array of dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift, nsdictionary

I have my array of dictionary like below:

```
var ArrayOfData: [[String: Any]] = []

ArrayOfData = [["ID": 18, "Data": <null>, "avgScore": 0],["ID": 8, "Data": <null>, "avgScore": 0],["ID": 9, "Data": <null>, "avgScore": 0]]
```

My `ArrayOfData` has the above values. But I need to update the particular object dictionary values based on my id.

I tried like below but I don't know how I can update the values.

```
for datas in ArrayOfData {
    var gameIdData = datas["ID"] as? Int
    if gameIdData == "18" {
        var gameData = datas
        gameData["avgScore"] ="123"
    }
}
```

I need to update my particular id object and again I need to append to my new array of dictionary or old array of dictionary.

My updated values should be like below:

```
var UpdatedArrayOfData: [[String: Any]] = []

ArrayOfData = [["ID": 18, "Data": <null>, "avgScore": 123],["ID": 8, "Data": <null>, "avgScore": 0],["ID": 9, "Data": <null>, "avgScore": 0]]
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

```
for index in ArrayOfData.indices {
if let gameId = ArrayOfData[index] ["ID"] as? Int {
    if gameId == 18 {
        ArrayOfData[index] ["avgScore"] = 123
    }
}
```

Use the index of the array to update the specific object.

Comment: after for statement, if i print my ArrayOfData. Its same nothing changes is updated to my ArrayOfData

Comment: Did you debug to see if its going to the if condition? If your game id is string, it wont go in if condition.

Comment: its not even going inside that `if let gameId = ArrayOfData[index] ["ID"] as? Int {`

Comment: Is your value of the "ID" int?